# How to make sure when scraping Bing URLs, that the URLs are actually found

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup, bing

I'm trying to scrape some URLs from Bing for a project. Once the Bing search has been found, I try to get all the links that were on the bing page into a list for further analysis. However, when using random keywords as the search, the list of URLs Found either work as expected or there are no links found. The keywords that no links change every time I use it.

```
def getBingLink(query):
    l=[]
    count = 0
    num = random.random()
    time.sleep(num)
    target_url="https://www.bing.com/search?q=" +query 
    headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Norton/121.0.0.0'}
    resp=requests.get(target_url, headers )
    print(resp.status_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    completeData = soup.find_all("li",{"class":"b_algo"})
    if (len(completeData) == 0):
        return l
    for i in range(0, len(completeData)):       
        o=completeData[i].find("a").get("href")    
        l.append(o)
        count = count +1
    return l
```

Today, when I use the word "doctor" as the keyword I get : `[]`
When I use the words "doctor who" as the keyword I get:

```
[[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who,...]
```

and other links which is what is expected.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't Bing have an API so you wouldn't need to use web scraping?

Comment: I'm unsure of how I would use one as this project that I'm doing needs quite a lot of searches ( possible 4,000 which I might have to repeat) and I don't have the spare cash to use.

Comment: I'll bet they have a rate limit on the web site, so doing thousands of searches with web scraping probably won't work, either.